# How to substitute generic anonymous functions?

Tags: scala, anonymous-function, function-signature

Suppose there is a trait for legged animals:

```
trait Legged {
  val legs: Int

  def updateLegs(legs: Int): Legged
}
```

And there two such legged animals:

```
case class Chicken(feathers: Int, legs: Int = 2) extends Legged {
  override def updateLegs(legs: Int): Legged = copy(legs = legs)
}

case class Dog(name: String, legs: Int = 4) extends Legged {
  override def updateLegs(legs: Int): Legged = copy(legs = legs)
}
```

There is also a holder for these animal, in a farm

```
case class Farm(chicken: Chicken, dog: Dog)
```

And a generic method to mutate all the legged animals by adding them one extra leg

```
def mutate(legged: Legged): Legged = legged.updateLegs(legged.legs + 1)
```

The question is how to implement a method on the `Farm` so that it takes the `mutate: Legged => Legged` function as a parameter and applies it to all the `Legged` animals?

```
val farm = Farm(Chicken(1500), Dog("Max"))
farm.mapAll(mutate) //this should return a farm whose animals have an extra leg
```

What I've come with thus far, but it doesn't actually work

```
trait LeggedFunc[T <: Legged] extends (T => T)


case class Farm(chicken: Chicken, dog: Dog) {
  def mapAll(leggedFunc: LeggedFunc[Legged]): Farm = {
    //todo how to implement?
    val c = leggedFunc[Chicken](chicken)
  }
}
```

I know how to do it with patter matching, but that leads to potential `MatchError`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A possible way to do that (type-safely, without using `asInstanceOf`) could be using object-dependant type.

First of all, we should add an abstract member that uses the concrete type of `Legged` subclasses:

```
sealed trait Legged { self =>
  type Me >: self.type <: Legged // F-Bounded like type, Me have to be the same type of the subclasses
  val legs: Int
  def updateLegs(legs: Int): Me
}
```

Then, the `Legged` subclasses became:

```
case class Chicken(feathers: Int, legs: Int = 2) extends Legged {
  type Me = Chicken
  override def updateLegs(legs: Int): Chicken = copy(legs = legs)
}

case class Dog(name: String, legs: Int = 4) extends Legged {
  type Me = Dog
  override def updateLegs(legs: Int): Dog = copy(legs = legs)
}
```

In this way, it is possible to define a function that returns the concrete subclass of the `Legged` passed (similar to what @Gaël J done):

```
trait LeggedFunc {
  def apply(a : Legged): a.Me
}

val mutate = new LeggedFunc { override def apply(legged: Legged): legged.Me = legged.updateLegs(legged.legs + 1) }
```

Finally, the `Farm` class is straightforward defined as:

```
case class Farm(chicken: Chicken, dog: Dog) {
  def mapAll(leggedFunc: LeggedFunc): Farm = {
    val c : Chicken = leggedFunc(chicken)
    val d : Dog = leggedFunc(dog)
    Farm(c, d)
  }
}
```

[Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/cric96/2oj3B8K1RnuFybGpAgwc1Q/4) for Scala 2

But why object-dependent type?
In Scala 3.0, it is possible to define `dependent function type` as:

```
type LeggedFunc = (l: Legged) => l.Me
val mutate: LeggedFunc = (l) => l.updateLegs(l.legs + 1)
```

Making this solution (object-dependent type) cleaner and type-safe.

[Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/cric96/45IKkx46Tb2QDkDuo60wqA/2) for Scala 3 version

Answer (score 2):

I'll just add to **@gianlucaaguzzi**'s answer that in Scala 2 dependent/polymorphic functions can be emulated with Shapeless

```
import shapeless.ops.hlist.Mapper
import shapeless.{Generic, HList, Poly1}

case class Farm(chicken: Chicken, dog: Dog) {
  def mapAll[L <: HList](mutate: Poly1)(implicit
    generic: Generic.Aux[Farm, L],
    mapper: Mapper.Aux[mutate.type, L, L]
  ): Farm = generic.from(mapper(generic.to(this)))
}

object mutate extends Poly1 {
  implicit def cse[T <: Legged]: Case.Aux[T, T#Me] = 
    at(legged => legged.updateLegs(legged.legs + 1))
}

val farm = Farm(Chicken(1500), Dog("Max"))
println(farm.mapAll(mutate)) // Farm(Chicken(1500,3),Dog(Max,5))
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using the method `asInstanceOf`

```
trait Legged {
  val legs: Int

  def updateLegs(legs: Int): Legged
}

case class Chicken(feathers: Int, legs: Int = 2) extends Legged {
  override def updateLegs(legs: Int): Legged = copy(legs = legs)
}

case class Dog(name: String, legs: Int = 4) extends Legged {
  override def updateLegs(legs: Int): Legged = copy(legs = legs)
}

case class Farm(chicken: Chicken, dog: Dog){
  
  def mapAll(leggedFunc: (Legged) => Legged): Farm = {
   
      copy(
           leggedFunc(chicken.asInstanceOf[Legged]).asInstanceOf[Chicken], 
           leggedFunc(dog.asInstanceOf[Legged]).asInstanceOf[Dog]
          )

   } 
}

def mutate(legged: Legged): Legged = legged.updateLegs(legged.legs + 1)

val farm = Farm(Chicken(1500), Dog("Max"))


println (farm.mapAll(mutate)) // prints: Farm(Chicken(1500,3),Dog(Max,5))
```

Try it on [scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/WI1AGpORSVGSAmNZEdPbpg).

**Update:** This is an alternative implementation more similar to your own code:

```
trait LeggedFunc[T <: Legged] extends (T => T)


case class Farm(chicken: Chicken, dog: Dog) {
  def mapAll(leggedFunc: LeggedFunc[ Legged]): Farm = {
    val c = leggedFunc(chicken).asInstanceOf[Chicken]
    val d = leggedFunc(dog).asInstanceOf[Dog]
    copy (c, d)
  }
}
```

Try it on [scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/n6EHL4IHQkycqFGxVAFRXg).

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd avoid most of the issues you encounter by having a truly generic `mutate` method (with a type parameter):

```
def mutate[T <: Legged](legged: T): T = legged.updateLegs(legged.legs + 1)
```

Then, when applied to a `Chicken` it will return back a `Chicken`, and same goes for `Dog`.

Comment: When I was trying the code on scastie, the errors were in the function definitions, not in the final application of `mutate`, when it was passed to `mapAll`.

Comment: The problem in this is case is which type parameter is applied when calling the method on the farm?